# Comparing percentage increase of datasets with different scales

Tags: dataset, mean, weighted-mean, weighted-data

I have N different datasets and my goal is to find the dataset with the biggest percentage increase in average price over all available years (Each dataset has the same number of years).

What is is the best method while taking into account the different number of transactions?

The format of each dataset is:

---

Year, Average Price, # of Transactions

2012, 10000, 100

2013, 5000, etc..

---

...My first thought was to calculate the percentage difference between the first and last year for each dataset. And then compare them against each other. However this wont work for a scenario with a high increases in average price over each year, except for the last year which has a much lower average price perhaps due to small number of transactions.